# pairing bluetooth digital speaker to mac

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, bluetooth

I just bought a Westinghouse digital bluetooth wireless speaker. Customer service doesn't know mac. Turned on bluetooth power with your help but don't know what to do now. Help please. think i need to pair them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to turn on your bluetooth speaker and enable the bluetooth feature first before working on the Mac.

On your Mac, go to **System Preferences**, look for **Bluetooth**, click on it. On the Bluetooth window, click **Turn Bluetooth On**. It will start looking for bluetooth enabled devices and if it finds it, it will show on the right side of the window. Then you can pair it from over there.